# AWS toolkit for VS Code SAM Local Code lence not working

Tags: aws-sam, aws-toolkit

VS code showed Code lence for **run local**, **debug** recently.
Suddenly it stopped showing code lence (for all projects I have).
AWS configured correctly.
Is this related to VS code monthly update.
How can I re-enable those options

[image]

Comment: i hate it when this happens. Might just keep my intellij license for another year.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install the AWS Toolkit for VSCode

- https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/

Here's a walkthru video for run/debug/local:

- https://youtu.be/FINV-VmCXms

Comment: not working. re-install toolkit, reset vs code settings in user folder, re-install VS Code. still no luck